# Reversing a git stash resulting in patch failed

Tags: git, git-stash

I had done a

```
git stash
```

and then

```
git rebase origin/master
```

which were both successful.

However

```
git stash apply
```

was not so happy:

```
$git stash apply
Auto-merging yarn/pom.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in yarn/pom.xml
Auto-merging unsafe/pom.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in unsafe/pom.xml
Auto-merging tools/pom.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in tools/pom.xml
Auto-merging streaming/pom.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in streaming/pom.xml
Auto-merging sql/hive/pom.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in sql/hive/pom.xml
Auto-merging sql/hive-thriftserver/pom.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in sql/hive-thriftserver/pom.xml
..
```

It seems a consensus approach for reverting the `apply` were:

```
$git stash show -p | git apply -R
```

However that results in:

```
error: patch failed: assembly/pom.xml:20
error: assembly/pom.xml: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: bagel/pom.xml:20
error: bagel/pom.xml: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: core/pom.xml:20
error: core/pom.xml: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: examples/pom.xml:20
error: examples/pom.xml: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: external/flume-assembly/pom.xml:20
..  and so on ..
```

So then is there any means to roll the whole `stash apply` back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your revert of the stashed changes fails for the same reason that applying the stashed changes did: the underlying content has changed too much, so the patch doesn't quite fit.

If you just want to revert all files to the contents of `HEAD`, all you need is:

```
git reset --hard
```

From the manual:

```
   git reset [<mode>] [<commit>]
       This form resets the current branch head to <commit> and possibly
       updates the index (resetting it to the tree of <commit>) and the
       working tree depending on <mode>. If <mode> is omitted, defaults to
       "--mixed". The <mode> must be one of the following:

       --hard
           Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files
           in the working tree since <commit> are discarded.
```

Comment: yes, aware of git reset (and had done that as a workaround) .. but would like to better understand what is incorrect/broken in the git stash revert.

Comment: Same problem that you had when applying the stashed changes: the underlying content has changed too much, so the patch doesn't quite fit.

Comment: actually your comment is important to the usefulness of your answer . Suggest you update your answer around it.

Comment: Well, you didn't ask why the `apply -R` failed. ;)   But sure, I can put it up there.